# Can anyone identify these uniforms (stated to be "Austrian")?

Tags: identification, uniform, austria, austria-hungary, prussia

I recently purchased these uniforms, in which I was told that they were "Austro-Hungarian/Austrian." Upon looking further at the lighter-green one, I noticed that it had a trim pattern similar to the Prussian/Imperial German style that I have never seen associated with Austrian designs. Since I cannot personally identify them with my knowledge of these uniforms, I was wondering if anyone here would be able to identify? I have attached images of what I believe are the production stamps inside them. I believe the one on the left says "PRF "ZF" Z81." I cannot make out what the one on the right says.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Stamps in both, with the left being the light green/red and the right being the darker green/black.]
[image: The uniforms.]

It is possible that the right-hand uniform is Napoleonic, as it does look similar to [designs of that era](http://www.rafaelpardoalmudi.com/images/figures/odd_grossbe/1812artpied01a.gif).
[image: Napoleonic foot artillery uniform]

Comment: Neat! Our identification questions are rarely as ... 3 dimensional as this one.

Comment: Can you get a closer photo or a scan of the stamps on the right one? The top right one seems like it says Łódź in fraktur, which would put these after the 1793 annexation by Prussia but before the 1815 Congress of Vienna which gave it to Congress Poland under Russia.